# AJAX code doesnt reload

Tags: php, ajax

Been trying to follow a tutorial: 
https://www.udemy.com/json-ajax-data-transfer-to-mysql-database-using-php/

There is a video in section 4: lecture 20

**script.js**

```
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = "";  

function submitData(fdata){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function(){ console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        jData();}
    xhttp.open(fdata.method,fdata.action,true);
    xhttp.send(new FormData(fdata));

    //console.log(fdata.method);
    return false;   
}


function jData(){
var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url ="json.php";
ajaxhttp.open("GET", url, true);
ajaxhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/json");

ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxhttp.readyState == 4 && ajaxhttp.status == 200){
        var jcontent = JSON.parse(ajaxhttp.responseText);

        for (var myObj in jcontent){
            output.innerHTML += '<div>' + jcontent[myObj].firstName + ' ' + jcontent[myObj].lastName + 
            ' ' + jcontent[myObj].age + '</div>';
        }
        console.log(jcontent);
    }
}
ajaxhttp.send();
}
```

I'm not so sure how I am suppose to put the other codes here since it requires a sql command but if ever someone could look at this code. The code is suppose to display the data and every time I insert a new data. It's suppose to display the new data at the bottom however the code does it displays all the data over and over again.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you setting a content-type header of a GET request. There is no request body so there is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: @Quentin it's a common practice for specifying the format you want, as `Accept` is used for negotiating content types and may just be a list of crap [the browser vendor thought should be included](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers)

Comment: @csixty4 — "it's a common practice for specifying the format you want" — No, it isn't. It's what you use to describe the format you are **sending**, it is the exact opposite of `Accept`.

Comment: @Quentin Semantically, yes. But that hasn't stopped REST API developers from using it for that purpose.

Comment: @csixty4 — *boggle*, I've never seen a REST API consume that in that way.

Comment: @Quentin if there's a way HTTP semantics can be abused, you can be sure REST developers have done it.